# Full Calendar v2.x shows times on event that expands more than 1 day

Tags: html, events, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar v3.4.0 and I have an event that spans more than one day. I wish to show the time of the event on each of the day it expands.
When searching StackOverflow I found an example that uses fullCalendar v2.2.0 and it shows the time on each of the days:

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/1916/ (note that on each day on the event it shows 10:00 - 6:00)

I used the code from that example, however it does not display the time the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/7yL1zuhp/ (note that the first day has 10:00 - 12:00, the second day has no time and the third day has 12:00 - 6:00)

Is there a way to get the time to display like the first example?

Code is the same in both examples, only change is the resources

```
HTML
<div id='calendar'></div>

JAVASCRIPT
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
defaultDate: '2014-09-15',
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
editable: true,
events: [
    {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2014-09-15T10:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-17T06:00:00'
    }
]
});

CSS
body {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#calendar {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: perhaps it doesn't bother showing the time in the middle day because it goes on all day? I'd say the newer version is better because it shows the times for _that specific day_. Saying "10:00-06:00" is actually a bit silly because it doesn't accurate describe the situation. You might imagine that the event was from 10am until 6pm each day (if you didn't notice the 24hr format, which many wouldn't, and didn't look carefully at the left-hand column). And it doesn't tell you on which days the 10pm and 6am occur. So actually a separate time period for each day makes a lot more sense IMHO.

Comment: If you think the middle day ought to show "00:00-23:59" or something then maybe submit a bug to the maintainer via GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like change in implementation in fullCalendar. You can solve this on your own by additional rendering. 
Please use event `eventAfterRender`

Here is fix example which is ready to extend to complete solution

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
    var $element = element.find('.fc-time');
    if ($element.length > 0) {
        return;
    }
    var $content = element.find('.fc-content');
    $content.prepend('<div class="fc-time" data-start="12:00" data-full="12:00 AM - 6:00 AM" style="margin-right: 2px; background-color: rebeccapurple;"><span>12:00 - 6:00</span></div>');


  }
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/ravnx49e/